# VBA saving tbl.ColumWidth as variable returns error 438?

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I'm trying to compare the current columnwidth to the autofit columnwidth like this:

```
Option Explicit
    Dim Tbl As Object
    Dim Col As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim OldColumnWidth As Integer
    Dim NewColumnWidth As Integer
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set Tbl = ListObjects("RuimteTabel")
    Col = Tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count
    For I = 1 To Col
        OldColumnWidth = Tbl.ListColumn(I).Range.ColumnWidth
        NewColumnWidth = Tbl.DataBodyRange.Column.AutoFit

        If NewColumnWidth < OldColumnWidth Then
            'Tbl.DataBodyRange = OldColumnWidth
        Else
            'Tbl.DataBodyRange = NewColumnWidth
        End If
    Next I
```

But whenever its at the `OldColumnWidth = Tbl.ListColumn(I).Range.ColumnWidth` line it gives the error:
 
Object doesn't support this property or method

I understand why the error occurs, but I do not see anything wrong with my code / how to fix the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in your syntax

```
OldColumnWidth = Tbl.ListColumns(I).Range.ColumnWidth
```

You're missing an `s` on the end of `ListColumns`.

I'd also recommend Dimming your variables as `Long` instead of `Integer`

Comment: Thanks, stupid that I didn't see that.
also, doesnt an Integer take up less space compared to a long?
i'll never get past 30 characters in a cell in my sheet so that's why I made it an integer for performance.

Comment: @Nemoko when you're looking at it for too long it becomes easy to miss the simplest things

Comment: @Nemoko - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long) for why `Long` is preferable to `Integer`. Basically there's no performance advantage, in fact there may be a slight disadvantage.